# Is maven-download-plugin not portable, or am I crazy?

Tags: maven, portability

**TL;DR**: I stumbled upon a situation where my `pom.xml` works fine on Windows, but fails on Linux. Since I'm rather new to maven, I'm not sure whether it's a common situation, or if I messed up somewhere.

**More details:**

I use the `maven-download-plugin` like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-download-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>get-stuff</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wget</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://myUrl/my.tar.gz</url>
          <unpack>true</unpack>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 <plugin>
```

On Windows it works like a charm (ie: it downloads and unpack).
On Linux, it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:maven-download-plugin:1.1.0:wget (get-moab) 
  on project my-project: Execution get-stuff of goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:maven-download-plugin:1.1.0:wget failed:
  An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:maven-download-plugin:1.1.0:wget: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.createArg()Lorg/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/Arg;
```

I found a workaround (`<unpack>false</unpack>`, and then "manually" unpack with `antrun`), but my pom.xml looked better without those additional 15 lines...

To put it in a nutshell:

- Is it actually a portability issue, or have I messed up somewhere?
- If it's an portability issue: is it common with maven, or am I unlucky on this one?

**More technical details:**

- I used the same plugin both on Linux and Windows (same version, same maven repository)
- It failed on a Centos, and a VM with Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

My first troubleshooting step when a build works on one machine and not another is to clean out the local Maven repository on the failing machine, and let Maven re-download all of the artifacts.  That's often enough to fix the problem.

If the build fails with the same error, then I clean out the local repository on the working machine and build.  Usually then I see that I've missed a dependency in the POM that just happened to exist in my local repository already.  Fixing the POM often makes the build work on both systems.

Comment: I tested that, but it yields the same behaviors. However, it was an relevant lead to test.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Maven versions (`mvn -version`)? `org.codehaus.plexus.util` is a dependency of Maven Core, so if `maven-download-plugin` is running under a different version of Maven it was compiled for, this would explain the error.

Comment: `3.1.1` both on my Windows and my CentOS. But that was an interesting idea, I didn't though of comparing maven versions.

Comment: I tried `maven-download-plugin` with various different Maven versions on my Ubuntu box, and I didn't see any problems.

Comment: Did you use `<unpack>true</unpack>` with a .tar.gz? (As far as I can see, this plugin works fine when it doesn't unpack)